# Problems with the For Loop That Checks if an Item of the same name exists already

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone explain to me why this isn't doing what I want it to do? I want the user to be able to input at least 5 items, however, I want to ensure that all items are unique. When they input the name of the item I want it to subsequently (check that there isn't another item already in there with the same name). I've got a (ranged based for loop) that iterates through the vector, however, when I put in two the same it doesn't loop back to the start it just continues, and for some reason it only checks and iterates through the vector once. Can someone please help me out? I've been working for hours trying to solve this.

```
bool Items::CheckIfItemExists(std::string &sInputName)
{
    for(const auto &Item : ItemsVec)
    {
        if (Item.GetItemName() == sInputName)
        {
            std::cout << "Item failed to add as there is already an item called that.\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
void Items::AddNewItem()
{
    bool bValid = false;
    std::string sInputName;
    double dInputSalePrice = 0;
    int iInputQuantity = 0;
    do{
    std::cout << "Enter information for new item...\n";
    std::cout << "\tName: ";
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::getline(std::cin,sInputName);
    bValid = CheckIfItemExists(sInputName);
    }while(bValid == false);

    bool bSalePriceValid = false;
    do{
        std::cout << "\tSale price: £";
        std::cin >> dInputSalePrice;
        if(!std::cin)
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Sorry, invalid input input. Try again!\n";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            bSalePriceValid = true;
        }
    }while(bSalePriceValid == false);

    bool bQuantityValid = false;
    do{
        std::cout << "\tQuantity sold: ";
        std::cin >> iInputQuantity;
        if(!std::cin)
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Sorry, invalid input input. Try again!\n";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            bQuantityValid = true;
        }
    }while(bQuantityValid == false);

    Item NewItem(sInputName, dInputSalePrice, iInputQuantity);
    ItemsVec.push_back(NewItem);
    std::cout << "You've succesfully added a new item.\n";

}
```

Comment: A good [mre] would skip most of that I/O. Instead it would simply hardcode the values that trigger the incorrect behavior. That is, don't rely on the user for input, and limit the output to what is needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please elaborate as I’m trying to fix this problem. I am a beginner programmer so so please cut me some slack.

Comment: A lot of detail is missing so this is just a guess: does the two methods reference the same ItemsVec?
The previous commenter tried to ask you to remove all the unnecessary clutter from the example so it is easier to help and also you can exclude some sources of failure.
Btw. for such a use case a set is more appropriate than a vector, its usage would result in simpler code.

Comment: @GeorgeBradley Elaborate? Umm... Skip most of that I/O? Seems pretty straightforward to me. If you think you need to get data from the user, don't. Skip it and hard-code a value to assign to your variable. If you think you need to inform the user of anything, skip it unless you need that output to demonstrate the problem. There should be no mention of `cin` and limited mentions of `cout`. Skip the **I**nput and **O**utput.

Comment: @GeorgeBradley Maybe an example would be better than an elaboration? After removing unnecessary I/O from `AddNewItem`, it might look like the following: `void Items::AddNewItem()
{
    std::string sInputName = "Hardcoded name";
    double dInputSalePrice = 20.0;
    int iInputQuantity = 10;

    if ( CheckIfItemExists(sInputName) ) {
        Item NewItem(sInputName, dInputSalePrice, iInputQuantity);
        ItemsVec.push_back(NewItem);
        std::cout << "You've succesfully added a new item.\n";
    }
}` (small enough to fit in a comment!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from the first call to `std::cin.ignore();`

When you first get an item name it ignores the first letter (so if you entered 'apple' you'd get back 'pple'). When you loop back to adding an item (I think) that same ignore call removes a newline so when you enter a name again you get the full name (e.g. 'apple').

I think things may work if you move the first call to `std::cin.ignore();` to after wherever you call AddNewItem() in a loop.

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you!